# Use Slider to set variable value, without touching the Slider first

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, slider

I have a short script attached to a Text-Gameobject, which sets the text to show the current value / position of a slider. This Text-Gameobject is attached to the sliders On Value Changed-field: ShowSliderValue -> [Dynamic float] TextUpdate

When I press Play, my text does not show the selected value / position immediately. Only when I change the position of the slider, the text changes from "New Text" to the actual value of my slider.
Technically I want to fire "On Value Changed" when I press play. This way I can avoid any unnecessary dependencies in my script.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ShowSliderValue : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Text text;

    void Awake()
    {
        text = this.GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    public void TextUpdate(float value)
    {
        text.text = value.ToString("0.00");
    }
}
```

While looking for a solution, I found the following video. At 5:06 (to 5:26) they set the default value from 1 to 30, and it just seems to work right out of the box. [Click here for youtube link.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQ8Tttcksu4&feature=youtu.be&t=306)

Is it possible for my text to show the slider value, without moving the slider first or actively asking for the slider value inside the shown script?

**Edit:**

Here is my current solution:
I add a script to my Slider that changes the Slider value on Start(). Since the value needs to actually change, **slider.value = slider.value** does not work.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class SliderTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        Slider slider = this.GetComponent<Slider>();

        float originalValue = slider.value;

        slider.value = slider.maxValue;
        slider.value = slider.minValue;

        slider.value = originalValue;
    }
}
```

This makes sure a value change will happen. Unless minValue = maxValue -which makes a slider obsolete anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this script that will set the text of the slider on the first frame and after that you could use your Textupdate function to set the texts value.
This is the script I made:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class SliderTutorial : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Slider slider;
    public TextMeshProUGUI txt;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        SetText();
    }

    public void SetText()
    {
        txt.SetText(slider.value.ToString());
    }
    public void TextUpdate(float value)
    {
        txt.SetText(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

You could also use something like this, that will constantly update the text from the script itself, and not the On Value Changed event.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class SliderTutorial : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Slider slider;
    public TextMeshProUGUI txt;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        txt.SetText(slider.value.ToString());
    }
}
```

If you have any more questions, feel free to ask them.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Saldy both options are not exactly what I am looking for. Like I tried to explain in my question: My script gets fed by the sliders On Value Changed-Field. So my text-gameobject does not depend on the existence of the slider. That means information are getting "send" from the slider to the text. Without any backwards dependencies (e.g. my text asking for the slider values).

So the easiest way would be if I could manually fire the On Value Changed-Field.

Comment: Also it is always good practice to use [SerializeField] private (...), insead if public (...) :)

Comment: I don't know about any solution in that case. Is it really necessary that you can't get the slider's value through script?  (the public variables were just to make the code cleaner but thx for the tip xD)

Answer (score 0):

Not the direct solution of this problem, but related to.
Just found on a dynamic use of the sliders that "slider.maxValue" has to be set BEFORE setting the "slider.value", if the given value is greater than maxvalue, maxValue is applied.
Hope this can help someone out there.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).